# how to add custom actions to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, swift4, backbarbuttonitem

I have a viewController (HomeViewController()) which is embedded into a NavigationCotroller and I have a horizontal CollectionView with 6 cells at the bottom of my viewController and I have implemented the delegate method `didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath`

Now when I select the any of the cell it will navigate to the respective viewController(`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerInstance, animated: true)`) lets call it "NewVC1()" as I am using pushViewController, it will create a back button for me and if I click on the back button it will pop back to the previous viewController. It is general scenario and working as expected.

In my case after selecting the collectionViewCell in "HomeViewController()" I will go the "NewVC1()"  and in there I have the same CollectionView as I have in the previous viewController(HomeViewController()) and now if I select any of the cells in the present viewController(NewVC1()) again I will navigate to the respective viewController(NewVC2()) same like before using pushViewController and Now, if I click on the back button in the "NewVC2()", I don't want to go to the "NewVC1()" and instead of that I want to go to "HomeViewController()".. How can I achieve this, is there any possibility of doing this?

I hope you understand what I am trying to convey and I am sorry if you can't understand my bad english and also sorry as I think this question looks very confusing..

**EDIT:**

Symbolically:

`let VC1 = HomeViewController()
 let VC2 = NewViewController1()
 let VC3 = NewViewController2()`

Navigation: VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 and if want to come back to VC1,

general case:

VC3 -> VC2 and VC2 -> VC1 (possible)

my case:

VC3 -> VC1 (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing from `VC2` to `VC3` use [setViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers). Then when you press back button from `VC3` it will come back to `VC1`

**Use this code in `VC2` `collectionView didSelectItemAt`**

```
let vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3") as? VC3
if var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    viewControllers.removeLast()
    viewControllers.append(vc3)
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro but I am pushing through collectionView. In the HomeViewController I have collectionView of 6 items and each item navigates to a different viewController and every individual viewController has the same collectionView like in HomeViewController where again I can navigate to any of the ViewControllers but when I press "Back" button it should come to HomeViewController. I am newly learning programming, I don't know anything about setViewControllers and I don't know where to use the code that you suggested.

Comment: I understood your question. You can use this answer for your concern.

Comment: But, where should I use the code you suggested? and what is the newVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 2 ways :

**First way - Create your own back button :**

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.back(sender:)))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton  

func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

**Second way - Use isMovingFromParentViewController :**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

if self.isMovingFromParentViewController {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mate and I tried both the ways and still can't get what I want. It is working normally as before. I edited the question for clarity, please take a look on edited part..